# Finding the same point with a Trimble DA2/QField and Trimble Zephyr 2.0/ Geo7x

Tags: qgis, qfield, trimble

The organisation I work for has historically used a Trimble Zephyr 2.0 receiver with a handheld Geo7x to find, map and mark out points in the field with 1cm accuracy. We use these instruments to mark out our agricultural field trials, some of which are over 100 years old, so accuracy is important. We also need these GPS points to have an accuracy of 1cm because this is what our tractor systems work to, and some of our field trial plots are only 1m by 1m. An error of even 10cm can make a big difference.

With a lot of help from our IT team around software compatibility, the Zephyr/Geo7x system has worked really well for us over the last 10 years but, as they are now switching off the 3G network in the UK, we need to upgrade and have chosen to pair a Trimble DA2 receiver with an Android tablet that runs QGIS/QField.

My problem is that I cannot get the two systems to find the same point location with 1cm accuracy. To test this we uploaded the same map (in WGS84) onto both systems and marked out several points using the old Zephyr/Geo7x. I then tried to navigate to these same points using the DA2 and QField, but was consistently about 20cm out (see below photographs).

As I mentioned, the map on both systems is the same but to make 100% certain this wasn’t the source of the error, I took a point location from a vertex in QField and entered the lat/long into the Geo7x to 7 decimal places (1cm resolution), and it gave me the exact the same vertex so I am confident the points in both devices are the same. We also tested both systems on two different days to make sure it wasn't a satellite/ positioning error, but both systems found the exact same point to 1cm resolution on both days (only the points were still in different places).

I am almost certain there is a difference between the settings but I can't figure out what it is. Below is the device setup as I have figured it out on both systems so far.

**DA2/ Trimble Mobile Manager/ QField:**

Trimble Mobile Manager settings: GNSS correction source = Auto (Trimble Correction Hub); GNSS output = Auto; Geoid = EGM96 (Global); licence = Trimble 1cm (10 hour pack)

QGIS settings: Layer CRS = WGS84, Project CRS = WGS84

QField settings: Positioning device in use = Internal Device (developer options enabled on the Android tablet to ensure we are connecting to the DA2), Antenna height = 2m (height of the pole that came with the DA2), Measure (M) attached to vertices = Timestamp (milliseconds since epoch)

**Trimble Zephyr/ Geo7x:**

Geo7x: GNSS Receiver port = COM3: GNSS Serial port (internal GNSS receiver); DOP type = PDOP, Max PDOP = 99.0; Min SNR = 12.0; System: Latitude/ Longitude; Datum: WGS 1984; Altitude reference = Height Above Ellipsoid (HAE)

I have also tried posting this on the Trimble help pages, but our supplier has told me they can't help with QGIS/QField, so also posting here in case that is the source of my problem.

[image: vertex 1]

[image: vertex 3]

Comment: What corrections are you using on the Geo 7x - I assume NTRIP to get 1cm but what's the source?  
And what country / city are you working in?